# python geometric mean calculation

Tags: python, math, statistics

How to calculate in Python and without `numpy` the geometric mean of a list of numbers in a safe way, so I do avoid `RuntimeWarning` which this function produces sometimes:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = reduce(mul, data) ** (1 / len(data))
```

I found out that i can use this log function to get the same result, but i have issue with log function not accepting negative values.

```
result = (1 / len(data)) * sum(list(map(math.log10, data)))
```

Can I map the data with abs function before map to log10?
Is there better way?

Comment: Taking a geometric mean with negative inputs doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ user2357112 Sorry i am just learning this stuff, can you expand your answer bit more? Why doesn't it make sense? What's wrong with that?

Comment: That's a math question. Ask it on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: get rid of the `list` call in your function by the way. It's going to store it all in memory. Do `result = sum(map(math.log10, data)) / len(data)`.

Comment: Josip, it is not exactly that it doesn't make sense at all but it is hard to come up with a scenario when it does. The thing is that the word "mean" suggests that its value should be between original values which might be not true if some values are negative. For example `gmean(-1, -4)` is `+2` which is obviously outside of the range `[-4; -1]`. This is actually manifestation of the same issue of not really being defined for negative values that you have.

Comment: Another question is why do you want to use `log` in the first place. Yes you can calculate `gmean(a[i])` as `exp(1/N * sum(log(a[i])) )` (**_note_** that you code misses the `exp` part) but it most probably will take more time to calculate unless you work with some really big numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally the n_th root of negative numbers are complex numbers

the code works with `cmath` base `e` `log`, `exponentiation`

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
from cmath import log, e

data = [1,2,3,4,5]

rmul = reduce(operator.mul, data) ** (1 / len(data))

rln = e**((1 / len(data)) * sum(list(map(log, data))))

rmul, rln
Out[95]: (2.605171084697352, (2.6051710846973517+0j))

data = [1,2,3,-4,5]

rmul = reduce(operator.mul, data) ** (1 / len(data))

rln = e**((1 / len(data)) * sum(list(map(log, data))))

rmul, rln
Out[96]: 
((2.1076276807743737+1.531281143283889j),
 (2.1076276807743732+1.5312811432838889j))
```

some checks:

```
abs(rln)
Out[97]: 2.6051710846973517

rln**5
Out[98]: (-120.00000000000003-1.4210854715202004e-14j)
```

for more fun and argument:

'the' square root of a positive valued `a` isn't singular, and positive, it is both the `+` and `-` signed values: `+/- sqrt(a)`

and 'the' square root of negative `a` is similarly both the `+/- 1j * sqrt(a)` values

Answer (score 1):

Geometric means with negative numbers are not well-defined. There are several workarounds available which depend on your application. Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371236/geometric-mean-of-negative-numbers-is-positive-or-negative) and also this [paper](http://www.arpapress.com/Volumes/Vol11Issue3/IJRRAS_11_3_08.pdf). The main points are:

1. When all the numbers are negative you may be able to define a geometric mean by temporarily suspending the signs, take geometric mean and add them back.
2. If you have mix of positive and negative numbers and if odd number of them are negative then the geometric means become undefined. In any case because you're ignoring the signs the result is not meaningfule
3. It may be possible to separately evaluate the positive and negative parts calculate the means and them combine them with some weights as the [paper](http://www.arpapress.com/Volumes/Vol11Issue3/IJRRAS_11_3_08.pdf) does but the accuracy will depend on various factors (also described).

In terms of the code I do not get a Runtime error (see code below). If you can show an example of your code I can try to reproduce that and update my answer. And yes you cannot pass negative values to log so you have to take the absolute values where appropriate (as described above). Note that with python 2 you have to either import division from `__future__()` module or use a floating point number when taking fractional power otherwise you'll get wrong result.

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> import operator
>>> result = reduce(operator.mul, data) ** (1 / len(data))
>>> result
1
>>> result = reduce(operator.mul, data) ** (1.0 / len(data))
>>> result
2.605171084697352
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. If a === minimum value in list, can i add (-a+1) to all members of list so i get smallest member to be 1, then there would be no problem to calculate the geometric mean, but is that allowed in maths?

Comment: I don't think addition by constant factor will keep it the same. Say you have three numbers x, y, z and you add a constant factor a. Before the mean was G = (x.y.z)^(1/3) and now it is G' = [(x+a)(y+a)(z+a)]^(1/3). Can you relate G and G' in a simple way so that if you calculate one you can get the other?

Comment: sry for the delay, i get "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars" when i try to calculate geo mean with reduce(mul, data_list) ** (1 / len(data_list)).  and data_list = numpy.sin(range(1,21))